# Reference that explores calculating the continuous limiting distribution of a sequence of discrete random variables

Tags: reference-request

I am trying to calculate the limiting distribution of a sequence of discrete random variables.

Is there a reference I can use that explores the techniques to use, and the theoretical aspects of what kind of convergence it is, etc. ?

Comment: That looks a rather general question.  What kind of thing is not in the Wikipedia article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_random_variables ?

Comment: Both volumes of Feller's _An introduction to probability theory and its applications_ have a lot of material on this.